# Switching between derived classes in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

This is the closest things I could find to a [possible duplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951504/changing-an-object-from-one-derived-class-to-anothe). However, the answers left me with questions still.

Here is a code sample:

```
class A {
   A() {}
   virtual void print() = 0;
}

class B : public A {
   B() {}
   void print() { printf("B"); }
}

class C : public A {
   C() {}
   void print() { printf("C"); }
}

int main() {
   A** n;

   n = new A*[4];
   n[0] = new B;
   n[1] = new C;
   n[2] = new B;
   n[3] = new C;

   for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      n[i]->print();
   printf("\n");

   delete n[0];
   delete n[1];
   delete n[2];
   delete n[3];
   delete [] n;
}
```

With this bit of code you get "BCBC". Is there a way to change the derived class type **without allocating a new object**? Something like:

```
n[2] = (C*)n[2];
```

So that when you print the array out you now get "BCCC". I read in the linked post that having to do this is evidence of poor design. If that is the case, could that be explained? This seems like it would be a normal and frequent use case for object oriented design to me. Assume that all attributes are defined in the base class. The only difference in the classes are in the implementation of methods.

If C++ does not support changing an objects type like this at run time, what is the accepted way to achieve similar results?

Comment: C++ does not support changing an objects type at runtime. It will be fixed when the object gets cretaed.

Comment: @PlasmaHH : n[i] is a pointer. Could't we use a child pointer to point to parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest thing would be to implement in B and C constructors that will accept A(or A*) as  input and copy any data need into new object. Then you should get something like this.

```
A* temp = n[2];  
n[2] = new C(A);  
delete temp;
```

But even better solution would be to create class that will hold data and A* pointing to a class implementing different ways of data manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

The object pointed to by the pointer `n[2]` is a `B` object. It can't be magically changed into a `C` object. If you want a `C` object, you're going to have to create one. However, don't forget to `delete` the existing `B` object.

```
delete n[2];
n[2] = new C;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can cast from class B to class C. Both of theses classes are also Class A, as in B is an A and C is an A however B is not a C and C is not an B. Either could be cast into A but this is a dangerous practice because of the slicing problem. In this case you have no data in the derived classes to be lost by casting so you aren't losing anything. However you don't need to cast a B or a C into an A in order to call the parent classes methods.

It would perhaps be possible to write a function that took a B object as input and returned a C object and a function that took a C object and returned a B object, but you would have to do all the work yourself manually converting one into the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can't *really* change the type of object once it's created. But it doesn't mean you can't change behavior in run time. What you need to do is refactor your code.

```
class A;

class ImplA
{
public:
  void print (A&) = 0;
};

class A
{
  std::unique_ptr<ImplA> impl;

public:
  A (ImplA* ia) : impl(ia)
  {}

  void print()
  {
    impl->print(*this);
  }

  void changeImpl (ImplA* ia)
  {
    impl.reset(ia);
  }
};
```

This is of course using C++11's smart pointers, but the idea is the same regardless. You apply the fundamental theorem of software engineering: abstract the thing that changes.

I recommend you read up on design patterns. It will arm you with ideas to do the things you want without breaking the way OOP works.